# C# Mastermind check result

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I am currently working on a project, mostly to learn and get more convident with the language. I decided to create a Mastermind game with Windows Forms, but I'm currently stuck. The problem is regarding how to make the program check a guess after each round.

To explain more detailed - assuming that you know the rules of Mastermind, after each time the player makes a guess where he put up what he thinks might be the correct colour order, he will get to know how many of his pins which were right colour on the right place, and right colour but on the wrong place. This is what im trying to do.

How I've gotten so far, in an attempted summarized version:

```
List<int> listRightAnswers = new List<int>(); //Same as bellow, but includes the right answers, previously picked randomly by the computer. (from index 0 to 3, always a value between 1 and 6)

List<int> listPlayerChoice = new List<int>(); //This list includes the player choises in form of integers. Index 0 would be which colour the player have put on place number 1.

int sum = 0; //
int RR = 0; //Number of right colours on right place
int RW = 0; //Number of right colour on wrong place

List<int> listCheck = new List<int>(); //This list is supposed to check if the place have already been checked.

int nrPlaces = 4;  //Number of places (pins)
int nrColours = 6; //Number of colours (how many different colours a pin can take. 1 = Red, 2 = Blue etc.)

for(int i = 0; i < nrPlaces; i++)
{
    listCheck.Insert(i,0);
    //Sets all indexes between 0 and 3 to 0 so that it can compare if the place is taken or not in a later command.
}

for(int i = 0; i < nrPlaces; i++)
{
    if(listRightAnswers[i] == listPlayerChoice[i])
    {
        RR += 1;
        ListCheck.Insert(i, 1); //Sets index i to 1 - will be used later
    }
}

if(RR == nrPlaces)
{
    //USER WIN - Program end here
}
else
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nrPlaces; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < nrPlaces; j++)
        {
            if(listCheck[j] == 0) // Is supposed to check if the pin have already been marked as RR and should then not count the pin once more.
            {
                if(listPlayerChoice[i] == listRightAnswers[j])
                {
                    RW += 1;
                    listCheck.Insert(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the futherest I've got but there are a huge bug and probably som minior too. Summarized, the method does not work as intended and I dont know what to do to fix it.

Works:
- RR will be the right number of right colours on right places.
- If there are no colours appearing multiple times, the method, as far as Ive tested, will work as intended

Dont Work:
- If there are either two of the same colour in the answer or as the player choice, RW does not get the intended value.

Hope I explained good enough, Im not too good at this.

Comment: What about an [actual algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Five-guess_algorithm) ?

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean with that. In any case, I want the program to be able to handle other than standard values (if number of pins or colours would be different).

Comment: What you don't understand ? The word algorithm ? If so, can't help you much more.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP, @FlorianF. Best I can tell, he wasn't looking for an algorithm to win a game of Mastermind, but just an algorithm to check whether the user's guess is correct. At least that's what I gleaned from the post.

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry that it is in german, but you will figure it out.

```
namespace Mastermind_2._0
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string A;//Navigation im Hauptmenü.
            string B;//Navigation in der Anleitung.
            string C;//Navigation im Spiel Menü.
            string D;//Navigation am Ende des Spieles vs. Freund bei Sieg.
            string E;//Navigation am Ende des Spieles vs. Freund bei Verlust.
            string F;//Navigation am Ende des Spieles vs. Computer bei Verlust.
            string G;//Navigation am Ende des Spieles vs. Computer bei Sieg.
            string Eingabe_Spieler1;//Freund vs. Freund string Eingabe.
            string Tipp;//Eingabe des Tippes von Spieler #2.
            int length;//Länge der Eingabe des Spieler #1.
            int Versuch = 0;//Anzahl der Versuche von Spieler #2, Default = 1, weil Spieler #2 auch beim ersten mal richtig liegen könnte.
            int Versuch_C= 1;
            int i;//Enumerator für den for- Loop. 
            int b;//-"-
            int correct = 0;//Zahl für die Anzahl an Richtigen. Bei correct = 8 -> Gewonnen.
            int correct_C= 0;// -"-
            char[] Möglichkeiten = { 'R', 'B', 'P', 'V', 'G', 'O' };//Array für die möglichen Farbkombinationen.

            //Hauptmenü.
            Menü:
            Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------Willkommen zu Mastermind----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\n                             [A]nleitung                                        ");
            Console.WriteLine("                             [S]pielen                                          ");
            Console.WriteLine("                             [B]eenden                                          ");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            //Die Variable A in einen string konvertieren.
            try
            {
                A = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar);
            }

            catch (System.ApplicationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                goto Menü;
            }

            catch (System.OverflowException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                goto Menü;
            }

            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                goto Menü;
            }
            //Die Methode .toUpper() anwenden. hallo wird zu HALLO.
            A = A.ToUpper();
            //switch -case statement anwenden als Kontrollstruktur (default).
            switch (A)
            {
                case "A":
                    //Anleitung besteht aus einer Zeile wegen der Übersicht.
                    Console.WriteLine("\n------------------------------------Anleitung-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWillkommen zu Mastermind. In diesem Spiel geht es darum deinen Freund oder\nden Computer zu besiegen. Dein Freund oder der Computer generiert einen\nFarbcode, der aus den Farben [R]ot [B]lau [P]ink [V]iolett [G]elb [O]range\nbestehen kann. Man hat 7 Versuche um den Farbcode zu erraten. Wenn man es\nnicht schafft gewinnt der Gegenspieler. Bei einem Versuch wird eine Farbe\nan der richtigen Stelle durch 'schwarz' gekennzeichnet. Bei einer richtigen\nFarbe, die jedoch an der falschen Stelle liegt kommt 'weiß'. Bei einer fal-\nschen Farbe kommt das Stichwort 'nichts'. Viel Spaß beim Spielen!");
                    //Zurück navigieren.
                    Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("[Z]urück");
                    Console.WriteLine("[S]pielen");
                    Console.WriteLine("[B]eenden");
                    B = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar);
                    B = B.ToUpper();
                    //Wenn B Z ist gehe zurück zu dem Menü.
                    if (B == "Z") {
                        goto Menü;
                    }
                    //Wenn B S ist gehe zu dem Abschnitt Spiel.
                    if (B == "S") {
                        goto Spiel;
                    }
                    //Wenn B, B ist beende das Programm.
                    if (B == "B")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bye...");
                        for (i = 1; i < 40; i++)
                        {
                            Console.SetWindowSize(i, i);
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                        }

                        Environment.Exit(0);    
                    }
                    //Kontrollstruktur.
                    if(B != "Z" || B != "S" || B != "B"){
                        Console.WriteLine("Ich verstehe das nicht...");
                        goto Menü;
                    }
                    break;
                case "S":
                    goto Spiel;
                case "B":
                    Console.WriteLine("Bye...");

                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ich verstehe das nicht...");
                    goto Menü;
            }
            //Spiel Menü mit einem case- statement.
        Spiel:
            Versuch = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("\n------------------------------------Spiel Menü----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\n--                         Gegen wen möchten sie spielen?                     --");
            Console.WriteLine("\n--                         vs. [C]omputer                                     --");
            Console.WriteLine("\n--                         vs. [F]reund                                       --");
            Console.WriteLine("\n--                         Zurück zum [H]auptmenü                             --");
            Console.WriteLine("\n--                         Zurück zum [S]pielmenü                             --");
            Console.WriteLine("\n--                         [B]eenden                                          --");
            Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            //Die Variable C in einen string konvertieren.
            C = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar);
            //Die Methode .toUpper() anwenden. hallo wird zu HALLO.
            C = C.ToUpper();
            //switch -case statement anwenden als Kontrollstruktur (default).
            switch (C)
            {
                //Gegen einen Computer spielen.
                case "C":
                    //Arrays erstellen
                string Tipp_C ="Default";
                char[] Farben_array = { 'R', 'B', 'P', 'V', 'G', 'O' };
                //leerer Array, der gefüllt wird
                char[] Computer_array = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };
                //Farbkombination erstellen
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int n = 0;
                do
                {
                    //Eine zufällige Nummer von 0 bis 5.
                    int rand = rnd.Next(0, 5);
                    //Die Position n (n erhöht sich um 1) ist gleich dem Objekt an Position "rand"
                    Computer_array[n] = Farben_array[rand];
                    n += 1;
                }
                //Tue das solange n kleiner als 4 ist.
                while (n < 4);

                //Menü
                Console.WriteLine("\nDer Code vom Computer wurde generiert...");
                do
                {
                    //Zurück zum Menü
                    Console.WriteLine("\nSpieler 2: {0}. Versuch.", Versuch_C);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEs gibt die Farben 'R', 'B', 'P', 'V', 'G'und 'O'");
                    try
                    {
                        Tipp_C = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                        bool contains = Tipp_C.Contains("1234567890");
                        if (contains == false) {
                            throw new System.ApplicationException("Der Tipp darf keine Zahlen beinhalten!");
                        }
                    }

                    catch (ApplicationException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                    //Tipp_C .Contains in Farben_array
                    char[] Tipp_C_array = Tipp_C.ToCharArray();
                    correct_C = 0;
                    for (b = 0; b < 4; b++)
                    {
                        if (Tipp_C_array[b] == Computer_array[b])
                        {
                            correct_C += 2;
                            Console.WriteLine("Black");
                        }
                        bool contains = Computer_array.Contains<char>(Tipp_C_array[b]);
                        if (contains == true && Tipp_C_array[b] != Computer_array[b])
                        {
                            correct_C += 1;
                            Console.WriteLine("White");
                        }
                        if (contains != true && Tipp_C_array[b] != Computer_array[b])
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("None");
                            correct_C += 0;
                        }
                    }
                    b = 0;
                    Versuch_C += 1;
                    if (correct_C == 8)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("\n--        Herzlichen Glückwunsch du hast es beim {0}. Versuch geschafft.        --", Versuch_C);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          Zurück zum [H]auptmenü                            --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          Zurück zum [S]piel Menü                           --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          [B]eenden                                         --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        Versuch_C = 1;
                        G = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar);
                        //Die Methode .toUpper() anwenden. hallo wird zu HALLO.
                        G = G.ToUpper();
                        //switch -case statement anwenden als Kontrollstruktur (default).
                        if (G == "S")
                        {
                            goto Spiel;
                        }
                        if (G == "H")
                        {
                            goto Menü;
                        }
                        if (G == "B")
                        {
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                        }
                        if (G != "S" || G != "B" || G != "H")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ich verstehe nicht...");
                            goto Spiel;
                        } 
                    }
                }
                while (Versuch_C != 8);
                Versuch_C = 1;
                Console.WriteLine("\n--                   Du hast es leider nicht geschafft...                     --", Versuch_C);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          Zurück zum [H]auptmenü                            --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          Zurück zum [S]piel Menü                           --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          [B]eenden                                         --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        F = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar);
                        //Die Methode .toUpper() anwenden. hallo wird zu HALLO.
                        F = F.ToUpper();
                        //switch -case statement anwenden als Kontrollstruktur (default).
                        if (F == "S")
                        {
                            goto Spiel;
                        }
                        if (F == "H")
                        {
                            goto Menü;
                        }
                        if (F == "B")
                        {
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                        }
                        if (F != "S" || F != "B" || F != "H")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ich verstehe nicht...");
                            goto Spiel;
                        } break;
                                //Gegen einen Freund spielen.
                case "F":
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n-----------------Spieler 1: Bitte wähle deine Farbcombination.------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n-- Diese kann aus [R]ot [B]lau [P]ink [V]iolett [G]elb oder [O]range bestehen --");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n--                Beispiel: BRVG                                              --");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n--                Dies würde Blau, Rot, Violett, Gelb bedeuten.               --");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nFarbcombination:");
                    Eingabe_Spieler1 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    length = Eingabe_Spieler1.Length;
                    //Kontrollstruktur. Hier die 2. hinzufügen
                    if (length != 4) {
                        goto case "F";
                    }
                Console.Clear();
                //do -while loop für das Vergleichen der arrays
                do
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Spieler 2: {0}. Versuch.", Versuch);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEs gibt die Farben 'R', 'B', 'P', 'V', 'G'und 'O'");
                    Tipp = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    //Tipp oder Eingabe Spieler #2 werden in einen char Array aufgebrochen
                    char[] Tipp_Array = Tipp.ToCharArray();
                    //Eingabe von Spieler #1 wird aufgebrochen in einen char Array
                    char[] Eingabe_Spieler1_Array = Eingabe_Spieler1.ToCharArray();
                    correct = 0; //Den integer correct auf 0 zurücksetzen
                    //Integer i um einen erhöhen. 0, 1, 2, 3. Jedes mal wird die Position gewechselt. Die Arrays werden verglichen in den folgenden Zeilen.
                    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        //Bei der richtigen Position und richtigen Farbe wird zu der Variabel correct 2 hinzugefügt.
                        if (Tipp_Array[i] == Eingabe_Spieler1_Array[i])
                        {
                            correct += 2;
                            Console.WriteLine("Schwarz");
                        }
                        //Boolean der entscheidet ob es einen weißen Stift gibt. Wenn contains richtig ist aber es die falsche Position hat gibt es einen weißen Stift. 
                        bool contains = Eingabe_Spieler1_Array.Contains<char>(Tipp_Array[i]);
                        if (contains == true && Tipp_Array[i] != Eingabe_Spieler1_Array[i])
                        {
                            //Correct erhöht sich um 1. 
                            correct += 1;
                            Console.WriteLine("Weiß");
                        }
                        //Wenn es die falsche Position ist und die Farbe nicht vorhanden ist gibt es keinen Stift.
                        if (contains != true && Tipp_Array[i] != Eingabe_Spieler1_Array[i])
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Nichts");
                            //Correct wir um 0 erhöht.
                            correct += 0;
                        }
                    }

                    i = 0;
                    Versuch += 1;

                    //Wenn correct 8 ist, d.h. dass 4 mal schwarz kam wird die Schleife beendet mit break; und man hat gewonnen
                    if (correct == 8)
                    {
                        Versuch -= 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--        Herzlichen Glückwunsch du hast es beim {0}. Versuch geschafft.        --", Versuch);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          Zurück zum [H]auptmenü                            --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          Zurück zum [S]piel Menü                           --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          [B]eenden                                         --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        D = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar);
                        //Die Methode .toUpper() anwenden. hallo wird zu HALLO.
                        D = D.ToUpper();
                        //switch -case statement anwenden als Kontrollstruktur (default).
                        if (D == "S")
                        {
                            goto Spiel;
                        }
                        if (D == "H")
                        {
                            goto Menü;
                        }
                        if (D == "B")
                        {
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                        }
                        if (D != "S" || D != "B" || D != "H")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ich verstehe nicht...");
                            goto Spiel;
                        } break;
                    }
                }
                //Solange Versuch nicht 8 ist wird diese Schleife wiederholt und wiederholt.
                while (Versuch != 8);
                Versuch = 1;
                Console.WriteLine("\n--                   Du hast es leider nicht geschafft...                     --", Versuch);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          Zurück zum [H]auptmenü                            --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          Zurück zum [S]piel Menü                           --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--                          [B]eenden                                         --");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        E = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar);
                        //Die Methode .toUpper() anwenden. hallo wird zu HALLO.
                        E = E.ToUpper();
                        //switch -case statement anwenden als Kontrollstruktur (default).
                        if (E == "S")
                        {
                            goto Spiel;
                        }
                        if (E == "H")
                        {
                            goto Menü;
                        }
                        if (E == "B")
                        {
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                        }
                        if (E != "S" || E != "B" || E != "H")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ich verstehe nicht...");
                            goto Spiel;
                        } break;
                case "H":
                    goto Menü;
                case "S":
                    goto Spiel;
                case "B":
                    Console.WriteLine("Bye...");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ich verstehe das nicht...");
                    goto Spiel;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `goto`s? why do you have everything in one method? why are you using one letter variables? Why did you not translate it to english before posting? what's with the `Console.SetWindowSize...Thread.Sleep()..` for loop? it seems truly unneccessary since you are doing `Environment.Exit(0);` right after. by the way, you should try to keep one `Random` in your program instead of recreating it every time.

Comment: It had been a while I hadn't seen such messy code :-)

Comment: "Ich verstehe das nicht..." – I think that summarizes the code structure as well.

Comment: @Default because 1) My level of programming is low. 2) Because when I use single letters as a variable it is either a enumerator for a loop or a string that I use to navigate in the menu. You can read everything in the comments behind the variables. I know its in german, but I didnt have time to translate it. 3) Ignore the .SetWindowize... it is just a little gag that worked, until I decided I better leave it out of the project, since it is for school... 4) Why only one? 
I was just trying to be helpful...

Comment: @Jcl Why is the code messy? I didn't use functions, so what. It still works and you can understand the code anyways. I seperated the variable types from each another and tried to keep it in order. Any recommendations on improving  my code structure?

Comment: Regarding `Random`: you can read about it in the documentation, in the section [Instantiating the random number generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

Comment: @JulianBuchel from your `so, what?`answer, I guess you don't find the usefulness of clean, separated, reusable code, and the value of well-named variables, then probably nothing I say would convince you of otherwise :-)